# Edit mode options missing?

Tags: edit-mode

Brand new to blender and imported a model from another program. Went into edit mode but not seeing any option for vertice, face, edge selection? Am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this moment the mesh is selected but the Metarig is Active (last selected, even if it's hidden). So you are in edit mode of the armature, not the mesh.

In object mode, press Alt H to unhide everything, click on the 3Dview background to unselect everything, then click on the character (it has to become yellowish, not orange), and go to Edit mode.

Comment: If the armature is hidden to not obstruct the view when editing the mesh, I would not unhide it... especially not `Alt`+`H` to unhide all, this can be very tedious in scenes where you maybe had hidden several objects for various reasons. Just hit `Tab` in the viewport to go back to _Object Mode_, then click on the mesh that should be edited and go back to _Edit Mode_.